# $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is injective & $ f(2x-f(x))=x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ then $f(x)=x $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be an injective function such that $ f(2x-f(x))=x$ for $x \in [0,1]$. I have to prove that $f(x)=x,  x\in [0,1]$.
My attempt:
let $$g(x)=2x-f(x)$$ then $$f(g(x))=x  \implies f$$ has an inverse, $$f^{-1}=2x-f(x) $$,
and I have no clue on how to proceed from here, the solution at the back of the back suggests defining a sequence $(x_{n})$ recursively as,   $(x_{n})=f(x_{n-1})$ but I couldn't understand it further.
Help  of any sort (hints or full solution, whatever seems possible) would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(2x -f(x)) = x, y=f(x), f(2y-f(y))=y$ implies that $f(2f(x)-f^2(x))=f(x)$

f injective $2f(x)-f^2(x)= x, 2x=4f(x)- 2f^2(x), 2x-f(x) = 3f(x)-2f^2(x)$ this implies
$f(2x-f(x))= f(3f(x)-2f^2(x))=x$ f injective

$3f(x)-2f^2(x)=x$, since $2f(x)-f^2(x)= x, f(x)=x$
$3f(x)-2f^2(x)-2(2f(x)-f^2(x))=-f(x)=x-2x$, thus f(x)=x

Comment: nice and really elementary solution, thanks!

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide : I do not not see how from $f(3f(x)-2f(f(x)))=x$ you get $3f(x)-2f(f(x))=x$. Can you explain ?

Comment: 2x-f(x)=3f(x)-f(f(x)) since f(2x-f(x))=x, ...

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide : Ok, we have $2x-f(x)=3f(x)-f(f(x))$. Then you have $f(3f(x)-2f(f(x)))=x$. But why have you then $3f(x)-2f(f(x))=x$ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but as the argument is **wrong** and to my surprise, it is chosen as the accepted answer, I felt I should say this. The step indicated by @Kelenner is in fact not valid. Your argument makes no use of the fact that $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$; if it was valid, it would also work for the case $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. But in that case, $f(x)=x$ is not the only solution, as $f(x)=x+c$ for any constant $c\in\mathbb R$ also works.

Answer (score 7):

I use what you have done. You have $f^{-1}(x)=2x-f(x)$. Now replace $x$ by $f(x)$, you get $f(f(x))-2f(x)+x=0$. Now fix $x$, and define $x_n$ by $x_1=x$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Replacing $x$ by $x_n$, you get $f(f(x_n))-2f(x_n)+x_n=0$, hence $x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1}+x_n=0$, or $x_{n+2 }-x_{n+1}=x_{n+1}-x_n$. This show that $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is a constant $c$, and $x_n=(n-1)c+x_1$. Now $c$ is zero because $x_n\in [0,1]$ for all $n$, and we get $x_2=f(x)=x_1=x$.

Comment: the book has used the same solution, though it is more clear here, but still I don't understand, how on earth someone would start assuming a sequence as above, maybe it is some method of solving functional equations, which I don't about.

Comment: Well, I have used the hint you have provided. Perhaps the only thing to note is that as $f(g(x))=x$, you have also $f(g(x))=x$, and then the hint make the method natural.

Comment: You have the functional equation $f(f(x)-2f(x)+x=0$, and the hint suggest to use the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. I think that putting $x=x_n$ in the functional equation is natural, but of course this is a matter of point of view.